# Do "Monster" mods apply to the "Unique boss" as well?

Tags: path-of-exile

In this map:

> Rarity: Rare
>   Forsaken Waste
>   Maze of the Minotaur Map
>
> ---
>
> Map Tier: 16
>   Item Quantity: +55% (augmented)
>   Item Rarity: +33% (augmented)
>   Monster Pack Size: +21% (augmented)
>
> ---
>
> Item Level: 83
>
> ---
>
> Area has patches of shocking ground
>   29% more Rare Monsters
>   46% more Monster Life
>   24% increased Monster Damage
>   Rare Monsters each have a Nemesis Mod
>
> ---
>
> Travel to this Map by using it in the Templar Laboratory or a personal Map Device. Maps can only be used once.

...do the monster mods also apply to the unique boss at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any mod that affects monster will affect all monsters on the map of any rarity including the map boss. It even affects things such as rogue exiles and invasion bosses. A similar question was asked on the forums and [Gary_GGG simply responded](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/1398581/page/1#p11455100)

> It affects all monsters on the map.

My personal experience is from fighting the Palace map version of Dominus with the "monsters have X% increased move, attack and cast speed" mod, which made it significantly harder to dodge his touch of god attack (and also why I remember it so well). Observing mods like speed are much easier to observe than mods you can't look at such as increased health or damage.